# Flutter flushbar/snackbar styling

Tags: flutter, styling, snackbar

I'm using the well known `flushbar` package in flutter to show flushbars/snackbars.

https://pub.dev/documentation/flushbar/latest/

I'm showing an error-flushbar with quite a small `title`, quite a big `message` and an `action/main-button`.

The problem is that my flushbar doesn't look nice because the `title` + `message` are positioned in a row next to the `action/main-button`. This makes the message quite unreadable because on multiple lines and the width of the flushbar is quite large. Is there a way to have the `title` and `message` positioned above the `action/main-button` so that the title and message use the full length of the flushbar and that the flushbar is less wide?

#### My flushbar-code atm:

```
    Flushbar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: _getFlushbarDuration(message)),
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.exclamationTriangle, color: Colors.red),
      title: 'ERREUR',
      isDismissible: true,
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      message: message,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.red,
      mainButton: FlatButton(
        onPressed: onPressMethod,
        child:
            Text('$buttonText', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[500])),
      ),
    ).show(this.context);
```

*This website is helpful for best practices using snackbars:*

In the tab **Action** under **Anatomy:**

https://material.io/components/snackbars/#anatomy

> If an action is long, it can be displayed on a third line.

#### UPDATE 1:

I've managed to do something resembling to what I wanted, though the height of the flushbar is still to big. There is a whole portion of the flushbar on top that could be removed + this solution doesn't seem the most beautiful one, code-wise:

```
    Flushbar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: _getFlushbarDuration(message)),
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.exclamationTriangle, color: Colors.red),
      messageText: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('ERREUR',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Text('$message', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[50])),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: onPressMethod,
              child: Text('$buttonText',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[500])),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 10),
      isDismissible: true,
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.red,
    ).show(this.context);
```

#### UPDATE 2:

This looks better, but I can't get the animation for the icon now because I added a container with margin to the icon. Still not happy with the fact I have to make the widget in the `messageText`. Would it be more appropriate to make this in the default `SnackBar()` widget?

```
    Flushbar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: _getFlushbarDuration(message)),
      icon: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
        child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.exclamationTriangle, color: Colors.red),
      ),
      messageText: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('ERREUR',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Text(
            '$message',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[50]),
            softWrap: true,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: onPressMethod,
              child: Text('$buttonText',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[500])),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      isDismissible: true,
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.red,
    ).show(this.context);
```

Answer (score 1):

`flushbar` has been discontinued. I suggest using `ScaffoldMessenger` to display a SnackBar instead. You can follow this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars) for more details.

If you'd like to have a "Title" and "Message" on your SnackBar, you can add a newline `\n` on the String to be displayed.

```dart
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Title \nMessage'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Undo',
    onPressed: () {
      // Some code to undo the change.
    },
  ),
);

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

[image: Demo]